# Find only id where in another column is only NULL

Tags: sql

Example table:

```
------------------------
| user_id | value|
------------------------
|   1     | NULL |
|   1     | NULL |
|   2     | NULL |
|   2     | 22   |
```

How to find user_id which has only `value` is NULL?
(in the example, the expected result: user_id: 1)

`SELECT * WHERE value is NULL` of course doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
select user_id
from t
group by user_id
having max(value) is null
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be working since its working. It seems sql server version issue :

[image]

```
select * from users where value IS NULL
```

Another way of checking the null values as below :

```
select * from users where value <> ''
```

[image]

Comment: What if each id is more than once?

Comment: it doesn't have any issue with the id

Comment: in your case, id is the primary key, in my case user_id is not the primary key